# Inset box shadow on unordered list not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to set an inset box shadow on an unordered list and it doesn't seem to be showing. I have listed the code below and a screenshot of the result.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```css
ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

ul:before {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #b7b7b7, 0 0 0 2px #fff, inset 0 0 15px #000;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    content:'';
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

li {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 19px 1em;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you also post the CSS for the `li` elements? Maybe they're masking the shadow.

Comment: Ahhhh! Ok thanks, will do that now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

The positioning of the list items should not be set to relative. Thanks to Jacob for point out it could be the list item masking it! :)

Comment: WOW that's an obscure thing. I also had to remove the background-color from mine, because otherwise, the li background appears above the ul box shadow, which makes zero sense, but whatever.